# Why am I still suspended for reviewing?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-suspension

On the 15th of December of 2021 I apparently made the wrong decision in a [triage question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/30594453) (it was spam instead of a community edit). I can live with that. I was suspended for 10 days till December the 25th.

However, it currently is the 31st of March 2022 and I'm still suspended... So either I was suspended for more than a year (which seems a bit overkill) or something else was wrong.

Comment: "I was suspended for 10 days till December the 25th." - no, you were suspended _on_ the 25th for a year. You've also been manually unsuspended now

Comment: *"which seems a bit overkill"* - For thinking that _blatant_ spam is redeemable by the community?

Comment: "either I was suspended for more than a year" Erm, am I missing something here? 15th/25th of December of 2021 until 31st of March 2022 is less than a year. Were you suspended in 2020 already?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "manually unsuspended", I imagine if the ban wasn't manually removed it would've been until 25th Dec 2022

Comment: What @NickstandswithUkraine said -- the ban would've lasted from 25.12.21 to 25.12.22. That isn't over a year. In fact, mods cannot suspend for over a year; only the review audit doubling can result in suspensions over a year. And possibly staff intervention, but I've never seen or heard about that happen for reviews so I can't confirm if that's the case.

Comment: If I was suspended on 15th of december of 2021 (which apparently was 25th, the triage failed at the 15th so it took another 10 days? ) and apparently the ban was until the 25th of december 2022 (which is thus more then a year if it started on the 15th). Nonetheless the period was vague (10 days or a year) and the date on which the ban started was vague as well. At least for me it was. But if the ban is for a year (although to me it feels excessive) I'll do the time.

Comment: @M.Deinum As Zoe said, it's already been manually removed, although I would suggest taking care of future spam posts :p

Comment: I'll take care. But apart from that, the period was a bit vague and not clear so that message could be conveyed in a clearer way. But maybe that is something for another question.

Comment: You don't need another question because you're absolutely right, this shouldn't happen.  This is definitely a bug; automatic bans aren't supposed to last this long.

Comment: Sorry for being daft. So the ban only said it goes until 25th of December, *but not which year*? Yes, then I can see how this is both confusing and led you to believe it was longer than a year, seeing how you thought it triggered on 15th. That sounds like a needlessly confusing UI indeed.